# How Can I Use Hibernate JPA @SQLInsert With a Database Column Having a Default Value

Tags: java, hibernate, default, sql-insert

I have a table "groups" with four columns.  The database is postgres and the group_id column is a Serial. So in reality it is an Integer with a default to get the next value.

I have a use case where I need to use @SQLInsert (using the normal persist method is not an option), but I can't get it to work with the default. Here is what I have:

```
@SQLInsert(sql="INSERT INTO groups (group_id, parent_id, group_name, version) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?)")
```

I set the entity attributes to values where group_id and version are null, and the other two are correctly populated. group_id is not nullable in the DB, version can be null.

I get this exception:

```
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22023
SEVERE: The column index is out of range: 4, number of columns: 3.
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
```

If I enter the following DML directly on the database, it works:

```
INSERT INTO groups (group_id, parent_id, group_name, version) VALUES (DEFAULT, 3, 'abcd', null);
```

Is there some way to make the same thing happen using @SQLInsert.

Comment: What are the types of variables which you want to save for version , etc. ?

Comment: version is a Long. This does work with a direct query... ie one done on the db, not through ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the short answer is "it can't be done this way". Despite quite a few places I've seen this asked, the Hibernate people have not provided for this use case.

My solution was to decouple the Postgres sequence from the table. That is, I removed the default constraint that selects the nextval from the sequence and populates one of the two primary key fields.

I then manually grab the nextval using a native query (yep, forced to un-abstract the database), and use that value to manually populate the primary key field. It works. It's kludgy, but I might use it more often. It certainly is a lot more understandable as to what is happening than using the pure ORM methods. This can be debugged without a wizards hat. :)

```
public class...
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistence_unit")
private EntityManager em;

...
mymethod(){
...
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT nextval('groups_group_id_seq')");
BigInteger groupId = (BigInteger)q.getSingleResult();

BigInteger parentId = methodToGetParentId();

GroupsPK gpk = new GroupsPK(groupId, parentId);

Groups grps = new Groups(gpk, "other parameters");

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class members which you want to save are not reference types they can not hold a null value. It may be the cause of failure in synchronization with database records. Try to use reference types like Integer and Double, etc. And get sure that default values are assumed with a direct insert query.

Another thing in your error messages. It may the default value is out of boundary of the type you are using in Java for that column. Check the default value to be in range. If a value out of range is set for your class member, it can't be synced.

EDIT: Sorry, the second part is not true in this case.